# Setting up loop in Excel VBA to repeatedly sum up specific range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a spreadsheet where I'm trying to repeatedly populate column K with specific data from various but similar points (80 cells down for each iteration) in column E.

So K2 should for example display the total of E25 + E35 + E42 + E56 + E63.

Then K3 should display the total of E105 + E185 + E122 + E136 + E143.

I have written a macro which does the first step (and works), which is as follows:

```
Sub disctoptest()

Dim source As Range
Dim destination As Range
Dim total As Long

Set destination = Range("K2")
Set source = Range("E25")

total = WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
source.Value + _
source.Offset(10, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(17, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(31, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(38, 0).Value)

destination.Select

destination.Value = total

Set source = Nothing
Set destination = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then I inserted a loop to repeat the operation for the entirety of the database, but whenever I run the added macro excel either freezes or simply refuses to work. This is the code I'm using to loop:

```
Sub disctop()

Dim source As Range
Dim destination As Range
Dim total As Long

Set destination = Range("K2")
Set source = Range("E25")

Do until destination.offset(0, -1) = ""

destination.Select

total = WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
source.Value + _
source.Offset(10, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(17, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(31, 0).Value + _
source.Offset(38, 0).Value)

destination.Value = total

source = source.Offset(80, 0)
destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

Range("A1").Activate

Set source = Nothing
Set destination = Nothing

End Sub
```

In case it might be easier to use a different kind of loop, I need to repeat the operation precisely 680 times in column K.

Any tips and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be done with a formula that can be drag filled down that would update automatically.

Comment: What formula is that?

Comment: You need to Set source and destination inside the loop.  You are creating an infinite loop, by putting the values of the offsets into the ranges and not resetting the range itself to the offset.

Comment: Put `=INDEX(E:E,25+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,35+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,42+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) + INDEX(E:E,56+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,63+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80))` in K2 and drag fill down as many rows as needed.

Comment: Did my answer work for you.  If so please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `SET` on the range variables to make them change to which cell they reference:

```
Set source = source.Offset(80, 0)
Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
```

Also

`destination.offset(0, -1) = ""` will never return true as the SUM function will return 0 even when all five references are empty.

So you will need to test something else like: `Total = 0`

---

Or you can do this with the following formula:

```
 =INDEX(E:E,25+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,35+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,42+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) + INDEX(E:E,56+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80)) +INDEX(E:E,63+((ROW(1:1)-1)*80))
```

Put in K2 and copy down.